# use keyword of pdftk is giving http 500 error

Tags: php, pdftk

I have ubuntu 18.04 and php 7.2 on my system.
I have installed pdftk using composer as mentioned in link: https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk.

But it gives http error 500 whenever I just write `use` keyword in php file. I am just trying to get result of `Generate FDF` and `get PDF Data`.
I have written this much code only for generating fdf.

```
use mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf;

// Create FDF from PDF
$pdf = new Pdf(getcwd().'/abc.pdf');
$pdf->generateFdfFile(getcwd().'/MyFolder/data.fdf');
```

My project folder structure is:

```
Project-abc
      MyFolder
      vendor
      abc.pdf
      composer.json
      composer.lock
      test.php                  // This is the file where code is written
```

It would be highly appreciable if anyone can suggest me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Check the apache log for some clue (/var/log/apache2/error.log). It can be a permissions error

Comment: @sochas - error.log is showing: 'PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'use' '

Comment: Is there any code above `use` that might not be correctly terminated?

Comment: @jrswgtr - Yes, I have written `require_once('vendor/autoload.php');`

Comment: Comment the use stament and try $pdf = new mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf(); Check if you have mikehaertl\pdftk\Pdf file correctly installed

Comment: @sochas - It gives error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Pdf' not found in /var/www/html/Project-abc/test.php:27 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/Project-abc/test.php on line 3` It gives error for line `$pdf = new Pdf(getcwd().'/abc.pdf');` when we comment the `use` statement

Comment: I think that autoloading is not working properly, please check this link https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/how-to-autoload-with-composer

Comment: @sochas - I have tried `use` keyword with slugy pachage `https://packagist.org/packages/cocur/slugify` and `use` keyword is working fine with slugify package, it means autoload is working fine. `use` keyword for pdftk is creating problem. Please once again have a look on folder structure.

Comment: @sochas - I have installed pdftk on system also. But still not working.